# How to push hash into array of hash in php?

Tags: php, hash

Like array_push() where we can push an element in to array. I want to push an hash [name,url] in to an array of hash.

Comment: Could you please describe what you mean with hash?

Comment: What is an "array of hash"? Are you looking for PHP's equivalent to Perl's hashes, "associative arrays"?

Comment: well, it's like map or key-value pair. I'm parsing few files in a for loop & i want to add both name of file & url of file into an array which is nothing but an array of map. i.e. i want to add or push a key,value pair into an array. i.e. array_push(name,url) to an array of map. I'm new to PHP...may be i'm wrong with the php terminology...but that is what i need to do.

Comment: Please read the PHP manual page on arrays to understand how they work in PHP. There's a link in my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ifif i understand your problem, you want to retrieve hash value from a url then use `parse_url` with **PHP_URL_FRAGMENT** argument

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

will return

```
 [fragment] => anchor
```

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)**

Comment: This is accepted? It seems to have nothing to do with the question :/

Comment: That's why I write it before code. Yes, you are right. This answer doesn't have anything to do with question.

Answer (score 8):

If you're referring to associative arrays where the key is user-provided (rather than an auto-incrementing numeric field), just use direct syntax:

```
$a = Array();
$a['name'] = 'url';
```

Note that `$a = Array(); array_push($a, 'lol');` is <sup>(almost)</sup> the same as `$a = Array(); $a[] = 'lol';`. `array_push` is just a (pointless) "shortcut" for the same syntax, which only works for automatic, numeric indexes.

**I *strongly* recommend reading [the PHP manual section on the topic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). That's what it's there for.**

Comment: +1 for pointing that `array_push()` is actually pointless in most of the situations and can be replaced with `$a[] = 'something'` (unless of course you want it to get the number of the elements after the update within the same line).

Answer (score 6):

I do not know, what do you need, but it you need to push pair of values into array, this may be your solution:

```
$hashes_array = array();

array_push($hashes_array, array(
    'name' => 'something1',
    'url' => 'http://www1',
));

array_push($hashes_array, array(
    'name' => 'something2',
    'url' => 'http://www2',
));
```

After that `$hashes_array` should look like that (each element of the bigger array is array itself - associative array with two keys and two values corresponding to them):

```
[
    ['name' => 'something1', 'url' => 'http://www1'],
    ['name' => 'something2', 'url' => 'http://www2']
]
```

Comment: Yes, i want this only. Now how can i map 2nd value from 1st value. [key/value] pair here ?

Comment: I need to sort 1st value [name] or key, 2nd value should also get sorted on that basis.

Comment: @mandy I did not understand what you are talking about, but the accepted answer shows that you were trying to find out how to create associative arrays. I did use associative arrays, but did not explain it the way you needed it to be explained, I think.

Comment: hey thanks...i was looking for something like hash or map [perl background], but associate arrays has done my job.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $aArrayOfHash['example'] = 'http://example.com/';
?>
```