# Adding multiple values to an associative array in PHP in one call

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I am trying instantiate an associative array and then in a second call, assign it various other value sets on one block-line.  I would like to do this following the same form as in the instantiation:

```
"variable"  = > 'value';
```

My instantiation is:

```
$post_values = array(
    "x_login"           => "API_LOGIN_ID",
    "x_tran_key"        => "TRANSACTION_KEY",
);
```

I would like to add:

```
"x_version"         => "3.1",
"x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",
"x_delim_char"      => "|",
"x_relay_response"  => "FALSE",
"x_state"           => "WA",
"x_zip"             => "98004"
```

What are my options?  Perhaps there's an array_push usage that I don't know about to add multiple values with more ease?  Or am i stuck adding on value per call like:

```
$post_values['x_version']='3.1'; 
 ....
$post_values['x_zip']='98004';
```

Is there any other graceful way to do add multiple values to an associative array in one line?

Comment: see related answer [in one call] here :: @the bottom;;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123122/how-to-push-hash-into-array-of-hash-in-php

Comment: It is unclear how the new data is accessed.  Is it an array?  Are they accessible as a individual variables?  Is `array_replace()` not suitable?  What is the desired output if keys are shared between the two arrays?  Robust [mcve]s are important.

Comment: Possibly tangentially related: [PHP is there a way to add elements calling a function from inside of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35548170/2943403) and [Merge two arrays into one multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24443086/2943403)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$post_values = array( 
    "x_login"           => "API_LOGIN_ID", 
    "x_tran_key"        => "TRANSACTION_KEY", 
); 

$array2 = array(
    "x_version"         => "3.1",  
    "x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",  
    "x_delim_char"      => "|",  
    "x_relay_response"  => "FALSE",  
    "x_state"           => "WA",  
    "x_zip"             => "98004"  
);

$result = $post_values + $array2;
```

Caution however: If the key already exists in $post_values it will not be overwritten.

Comment: Seems array_merge overwrites, where + is the same function but does not overwrite.  

Got it, thanks :)

Comment: You can also use `+=` operator like so `$post_values += ['x_version' => '3.1', 'x_zip' => 98004];`

Answer (score 6):

In order to keep things nice and clean and in this case, simple, you might be better off using [array_merge( )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

I personally declare any arrays at the top of my class file, in order to make them globally accessible, only because I tend to keep methods free of array declaration (OCD I guess!)

So for me I have an example that might help you, it's something that works for me when needed to add/merge two arrays together:

```
protected $array1 = array (
  'basic'   => '1',
  'example' => '2',
  'for'     => '3'  
);

protected $array2 = array(
  'merging'     => '4',
  'two'         => '5',
  'associative' => '6',
  'arrays'      => '7',
  'mate'        => '8'
);
```

Then within your class file, you can use these arrays or any created arrays and merge whenever you want:

```
public function ExampleOne() 
{
  $firstArray = $this->array1;
  print_r($firstArray);
  
  $secondArray = $this->array2;
  print_r($secondArray);

  $merged = array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray);
  print_r($merged);
}
```

Each print_r( ) will give you a print out in the console of the data/created array. This is so you can view for yourself that everything has been created correctly and each key has its associated value (check the PHP man pages for a definitive explanation of [print_r( )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) ).

So, the first array will/should showcase this:

```
Array
(
  [basic]   => 1
  [example] => 2
  [for]     => 3
)
```

The second array will/should showcase this:

```
Array
(
  [merging]     => 4
  [two]         => 5
  [associative] => 6
  [arrays]      => 7
  [mate]        => 8
)
```

And the array_merge( ) operation will create the final array, which will/should showcase this:

```
Array
(
  [basic]       => 1
  [example]     => 2
  [for]         => 3
  [merging]     => 4
  [two]         => 5
  [associative] => 6
  [arrays]      => 7
  [mate]        => 8
)
```

Of course, you don't always have to place/create your arrays at the top of the class file and when needed you can obviously create arrays within a single function if they are only needed/used within there - what I showcased here was just something I had done recently for a project at work (with the data in these arrays being example data of course!)

Answer (score 2):

[`array_push()`](https://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php)  will accept an array to be pushed.
But [`array_merge()`](https://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) may be more what you want.

Comment: `array_push()` will not preserve associative keys on its own.  This answer is either misleading or needs to be better explained about caveats.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following function: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: This doc-link answer could have been posted as a comment under the question because it only endeavors to redirect traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the spread operator:

```
$post_values = [ 
    "x_login"    => "aaa", 
    "x_tran_key" => "bbb", 
];

$dataToAdd = [
    "foo" => "abc",  
    "bar" => "def",  
];

$result = [
    ...$post_values,
    ...$dataToAdd
];

print_r($result);
```

Which results to:

```
Array
(
    [x_login] => aaa
    [x_tran_key] => bbb
    [foo] => abc
    [bar] => def
)
```

Comment: I am interested in seeing the benchmarking script and sample data that you used to prove that unpacking multiple arrays into an array "is faster".  [Splatpacking versus array_values() to re-index an array with numeric keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57725811/2943403) seems to indicate that unpacking, just to re-pack is not a performant solution.  I would be surprised if your snippet outperformed the `array union` operator.  It would be helpful to compare your suggestion against all other similarly functioning techniques.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, here's a snippet of what I ment: https://onlinephp.io?s=lZBBa8JAEIXPDeQ_TCVgQmyM6a1qexJ6aKkgPYnIYlazpe6EyYYipf-9sxsVCwnUU3Ym82be9yZPZVH63nAIM20kwQFrgg3mEgpJcgBSf-Dh1vd8L6BaVzCFUZqmY9tgjSASh_Ve0k6C0vCJyLsCk_LYXm0IjdrL0FAtI1YEuTCC_yxXXGyRIAwUl-kY-DsBt9--4ziCb9-7Oc1fHAldbwDLsDKk9C6y0ukj9LeIfUi4WtlLP9bEq3PVZkRuCoSeW_gAPZaFp-k7YPMRd-bP8_Xs7aWN80uZAqqSpMgBS0nCINl7o27o7FrqbLmykm7KI-Rp-WVESZI0fXfeLBqn3Tk0KOcgjvM2iVFLErVWqP9wZ93c99dyW8HxEf8D37w7N91szu0ZrZm2ZNkl2S8%2C&v=8.2.13

I might not have been clear enough how I meant that, so I removed the hint to performance in my post...

Comment: Please review this adjusted benchmarking script where I've isolated the operations into separate functions. https://3v4l.org/J78dk

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to avoid complications and mixups, simply use +=

Example:

```
$data = ["one" => 1];
$data += [ "two" => 2 ];
$data += [ "three" => 3, "four" => 4];
print_r($data);
```

Result:
Array ( [one] => 1 [two] => 2 [three] => 3 [four] => 4 )