# Merge two arrays into one multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two seperate arrays. One with the IDs of the target, and one with the name of the target. Both are in cronilogical order.

Example:

```
  $array[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 113139803806479652682
        [1] => 100276549585470687394
    )
```

and

```
 $array[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => EDM
        [1] => Space
    )
```

So in $array[1] the [0] in that is the ID for "EDM" (as seen in $array[2]) and then [1] in $array[1] is the name ID for "Space".

What I want to achieve is outputting a new array which would look like this:

```
  [0] => Array
 ( 
  [0] => 113139803806479652682
  [1] => EDM
 )
  [1] => Array
 (
 [0] => 100276549585470687394
 [1] => Space
 )
```

Basically a new array which returns a multiple dimensional array with the ID and name in the same array as taken from the two sepearte arrays that had the names and IDs in order already, just I want them formed so they go together.

I hope this makes sense. I'm kind of new to PHP and coding in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = [];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $results[$key] = [$array1[$key],$array2[$key]];
}
```

Comment: Well. My array I'm working with is already a multi dimensional array. I basically want to combine the results of [1] and [4] ([1] being the IDs and [4] being the names) into a new multi-dimensional array combinging the IDs and names into each other's array. If that makes any since.

Comment: maybe `$results[$key] = [$array1[$key][1],$array2[$key][4]]`? if your array is different from what's shown in the question, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $newarray=array();

foreach($array1 as $k=>$val){

  $newarray[$k]['ID'] = $val;
  $newarray[$k]['name'] = $array2[$k];

}
```

Comment: What's this code about? You should include brief too.

Comment: This solution takes the OP's plain English too literally and does not provide the desired result.  Also, these are not separate arrays, they are two subarrays within a parent array.

Answer (score 0):

It may be not the most elegant solution, but it'll do the trick. Here the code:

```
$arraySum = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
    $arraySum[$i][$i] = $array1[$i];
    $arraySum[$i][$i+1] = $array2[$i];
}
```

Comment: Calling `count()` on each iteration of the loop is not best practice -- it should be cached.  There is no `$array1` nor `$array2` to use so this code will not work for the posted question.  `$arraySum` is a poor choice for a variable name because it does not contain any summed data.  All answers, even simple ones, should be explained to researchers.

Answer (score 0):

By calling upon `array_map()` with a `null` callback parameter and a "splat operator" on `$array` to "unpack it" as multiple single-dimensional input arrays, you can cleverly generate your desired, re-indexed output array in a concise one-liner.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J7Zf4))

```
$array[1] = [
     '113139803806479652682',
     '100276549585470687394'
];

$array[2] = [
     'EDM',
     'Space'
];

var_export(array_map(null, ...$array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '113139803806479652682',
    1 => 'EDM',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '100276549585470687394',
    1 => 'Space',
  ),
)
```