# PHP is there a way to add elements calling a function from inside of array

Tags: php

I want to add multiple values from inside of array calling a function:

```
$header = array(
  'name',
  'surname',
  _create_days(),
  'total'
);
```

So output be like

```
$header = array(
  'name',
  'surname',
  '2016-01-01',
  '2016-01-02',
  ....
  'total'
);
```

I've tried with array_push, array_merge but didn't work.

Comment: I know that i can split the array, so
'$header = array("name", "surname");
 $header[] = _create_days();
$header[] = "total";'
But I have a big array, so I want to save some space

Comment: what space to save? you already have the solution.. don't worry about the space.. there's nothing to save

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? what space?

Comment: Please let us know what your _create_days() function looks like ?

Comment: I generate array for `php-excel`, so I have  multidimensional array that is like 1200 lines declaration, so it's like not readable now and after splinting it, it will be very hard to read

Comment: if your function returns proper array, integer or string, it should work just fine..

Comment: `function _create_days(DateTime $start_date, DateTime $end_date) {
  $array_of_days = array();
  $interval     = new DateInterval('P1D');
  $daterange    = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval ,$end_date);
  foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $array_of_days[] = array(
      'data' => $date->format('D'),
      'width' => 4,
    );
  }
return $array_of_days;
`

Comment: did you check if this function returns any valid data ? something like print_r(time_create_days(date1, date2)) perhaps ?

Comment: I think he want to add all the array elements returning from function inside the newly creating array.

Comment: Function return valid data
And Yes, i wan to add all the data from function inside my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you wrote it in the question. The function `_create_days()` is called and it returns a value that replaces the function call. Even if the function returns multiple values in an array, the array as a whole is placed in the outer array you want to build.

The solution is to write the function `_create_days()` to return an array of values and merge this returned array into the outer array using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for example:

```
function _create_days()
{
    return array(
        '2016-01-01',
        '2016-01-02',
    );
}

$header = array_merge(
    array(
        'name',
        'surname',
    ),
    _create_days(),
    array(
        'total',
    )
);
```

Another option is to use a placeholder when you build `$header` and replace it later with the values returned by `_create_days()` using the function [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$header = array(
    'name',
    'surname',
    '@days@',           // this is the placeholder
    'total',
);

// Replace the placeholder with the values returned by _create_days()
array_splice(
    $header,
    array_search('@days@', $header),
    1,
    _create_days()
);
```

In order to make the code flexible I used the function [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the position of the placeholder in `$headers`. This way, if you add or remove elements before `'@days@'` the code still works without any adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to iterate through the array after you've created it, you can simply use special values for callbacks that you want to call:

**Example:**

```
<?php

function _create_days() {
    return [
        '2016-01-01',
        '2016-01-02',
    ];
}

$header = [
  'name',
  'surname',
  ['_create_days'], // We know it's a callback because it's an array
  'total',
];

$headerNew = [];

foreach ($header as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        // If the length of $value is above 1 then it's a class callback, else just set it to the first item
        $callback = count($value) > 1 ? $value : $value[0];

        // Get the actual array from the callback
        $value = call_user_func($callback);

        // Merge the $headerNew array with the new values
        $headerNew = array_merge($headerNew, $value);
    } else {
        // It's not a callback, just use the actual value
        $headerNew[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($headerNew);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => surname
    [2] => 2016-01-01
    [3] => 2016-01-02
    [4] => total
)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/522964)

---

**Note:**

If you have any *actual* arrays in the `$header` array this makes things a little more difficult, as we can't check if you're using an array. For that you can simply create an instance of a class:

```
<?php

// (_create_days function)

class ValueCallback {
    protected $callback;

    public function __construct($callback) {
        if (is_array($callback)) {
            $callback = count($callback) > 1 ? $callback : $callback[0];
        }

        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return call_user_func($this->callback);
    }
}

$header = [
  'name',
  'surname',
  new ValueCallback('_create_days'),
  'total',
];

$headerNew = [];

foreach ($header as $value) {
    if ($value instanceof ValueCallback) {
        // Get the actual array from the callback
        $value = $value->getValue();

        // Merge the $headerNew array with the new values
        $headerNew = array_merge($headerNew, $value);
    } else {
        // It's not a callback, just use the actual value
        $headerNew[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($headerNew);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/522973)

Answer (score 0):

From PHP7.4, just unpack/spread your function's return value directly into the result array with (`...` -- the spread operator).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Dfg3k))

```
function _create_days() {
    return ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02'];
}

$header = [
    'name',
    'surname',
    ..._create_days(),
    'total',
];

var_export($header);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'name',
  1 => 'surname',
  2 => '2016-01-01',
  3 => '2016-01-02',
  4 => 'total',
)
```