# Assigning null to array element is still considered a valid array element

Tags: php

Why is this still returning a count of 3 ?

```
$arr =
[
    [
        'slug' => 'products-services-pricing',
        'text' => 'Products/Services and Pricing',
    ],
    [
        'slug' => 'promotions-plan',
        'text' => 'Promotions Plan',
    ],
    (1 == 2) ?
    [
        'slug' => 'distribution-plan',
        'text' => 'Distribution Plan',
    ] : null,
];

echo "Count = ".count($arr)."\n";
print_r($arr);
```

My `foreach` is getting messed up. PHP 8.0
I cannot do condition check in `foreach` because I am using `count`.

Comment: The value of the third element is `null`, there is no problem with that, no mistery. You are not removing the element, but assigning it a value: `null`. Here you got an idea: iterate over the array and remove elements valued `null`. Or simply iterate to count not `null` elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Condition in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440186/condition-in-array)

Comment: @shingo - 74440186/condition-in-array - This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sure, a `null` valued element is still considered a valid array element!**

For example:

```
<?php
$arr = [null, null, null];

echo 'Count: ' . count($arr); //Will print 3
```

In your code, the value of the third element is `null`, there is no problem with that, no mistery. You are not removing the element, but assigning it a value: `null`.

Here you got an idea: iterate over the array and remove elements valued null:

```
$aux = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (!is_null($item)) {
        $aux[] = $item;
    }
}
$arr = $aux; //Now $arr has no null elements
```

Or simply iterate to count not null elements.

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (!is_null($item)) {
        $c++;
    }
}
echo 'Count: ' . $c; //Count without null elements
```

Or you can build your array adding or not the conditional element. This can be the better solution:

```
$arr =
[
    [
        'slug' => 'products-services-pricing',
        'text' => 'Products/Services and Pricing',
    ],
    [
        'slug' => 'promotions-plan',
        'text' => 'Promotions Plan',
    ],
];

if (1 == 2) {
    $arr[] = [
        'slug' => 'distribution-plan',
        'text' => 'Distribution Plan',
    ];
}

echo 'Count: ' . count($arr); //Will print 2
```

Comment: This is a more work since the actual array is a multi-dimensional one - is there a way to do if condition in the array assignment as opposed to using ternary operator ?

Comment: Sure, you can build your array adding or not the conditional element. I edited my answer, look last code sample. Maybe is the better and more efficient way to goal what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the values returned by your ternary and use the spread operator, you'll be able to achieve what you want without any subsequent filtering or fooling around.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/295lV))

```
...(1 == 2)
    ? [['slug' => 'distribution-plan', 'text' => 'Distribution Plan']]
    : [],
```

By adding a level of depth to the true branch value, the spread operator will push the single row into the array.

By changing `null` to an empty array, the spread operator will push nothing into the array.

Kind of, sort of, related:

[PHP is there a way to add elements calling a function from inside of array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74285246/2943403)