# PHP | Add additional keys and values to an associative array by function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to add additional keys and values to an associative array by function.
I try to simplify my desire to this very simple example.

**For example, I have the following array:**

```php
$array = array (
    'key1' => array(
        'attribute1' => 'value1',
        'attribute2' => 'value2',
        'attribute3' => 'value3',
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'attribute1' => 'value1',
        'attribute2' => 'value2',
        'attribute3' => 'value3',
    )
);
```

**While creating the array, some elements should come from a function:**

```
$array = array (
    'key1' => array(
        'attribute1' => 'value1',
        'attribute2' => 'value2',
        'attribute3' => 'value3',
    ),
    getArrayElements(),
    'key2' => array(
        'attribute1' => 'value1',
        'attribute2' => 'value2',
        'attribute3' => 'value3',
    )
);

function getArrayElements()
{
    $new_array = array (
        'additional_key_1'  => array(
            'attribute1' => 'value1',
            'attribute2' => 'value2',
            'attribute3' => 'value3',
        ),
        'additional_key_2'  => array(
            'attribute1' => 'value1',
            'attribute2' => 'value2',
            'attribute3' => 'value3',
        ),
    );
    return $new_array;
}
```

**I get the following result:**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [additional_key_1] => Array
                (
                    [attribute1] => value1
                    [attribute2] => value2
                    [attribute3] => value3
                )

            [additional_key_2] => Array
                (
                    [attribute1] => value1
                    [attribute2] => value2
                    [attribute3] => value3
                )

        )
    [key2] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
)
```

**I would like to have this result**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
    [additional_key_1] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
    [additional_key_2] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
    [key2] => Array
        (
            [attribute1] => value1
            [attribute2] => value2
            [attribute3] => value3
        )
)
```

***Is this possible? How can I achieve this?***

Comment: [Three dots does it all.](https://3v4l.org/20IHE)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a downside to it? In the following post nobody accepted it as answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548170/php-is-there-a-way-to-add-elements-calling-a-function-from-inside-of-array

Comment: You can show your appreciation on the provided page.  (You shouldn't write "thank you"s as comments.)  Don't trust the answer scores.  I often answer old questions, so my answers take a while before they bubble up to the top.  You can help it get there. @Phantom

Comment: Prior to PHP7.4, the technique fails with `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS), expecting ']'` This is no longer concern because everyone should be programming on more modern, supported versions of PHP. @Phantom

Comment: Is there also a solution for PHP7.3? Thanks for the clarification @mickmackusa

Comment: You can be quite confident that the other working answers from 7 years ago will work fine for PHP7.3.  If you are working in PHP7.3, I recommend that you tell your boss that you are going to quit and find a PHP development role at a company that is going to nurture your professional growth by providing a modern/secure environment.

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_merge()`.

```
$array = array_merge(
    array (
        'key1' => array(
            'attribute1' => 'value1',
            'attribute2' => 'value2',
            'attribute3' => 'value3',
        ),
        'key2' => array(
            'attribute1' => 'value1',
            'attribute2' => 'value2',
            'attribute3' => 'value3',
        )
    ), 
    get_array_elements()
);
```